# Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build

I am new to Android development and tried to Run my project; so I insted plugged in my own Mobile Phone(Android) with USB and ran it but got one error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**Build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.axel.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: add this under android tag    dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}    and try

Comment: Also update your jdk version to 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `multiDexEnabled` is used to cross the limit of 64K methods, It is required in Dalvik system.

**Reference link** - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Remove this line from your **build.gradle**

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: thank you for the help - i tried Eliahu Horwitz answer and it worked so didn't need to use this one but sure itd helped as well. also thanks for changing my thread(question) to the right format so people could understand.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

and

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
```

to

```
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
```

I think build tools v 24 requires java 8